# Python / Pandas - Creating a condensed dataframe of groups

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
          group  groupError level2_error  level3_error      level4_error
170  64.22-1-00   0.109667      0.109667      0.109667          0.168453
72   64.22-1-00   0.109667      0.109667      0.109667          0.168453
121  41.20-4-00    4.00153       4.00153       4.00153           9.65689
99   35.12-3-00    4.81931       4.81931       4.81931        -0.0652749
19   64.22-1-00   0.109667      0.109667      0.109667          0.168453
91   35.12-3-00    4.81931       4.81931       4.81931        -0.0652749
86   41.20-4-00    4.00153       4.00153       4.00153           9.65689
108  41.20-4-00    4.00153       4.00153       4.00153           9.65689
241  35.12-3-00    4.81931       4.81931       4.81931        -0.0652749
88   35.12-3-00    4.81931       4.81931       4.81931        -0.0652749
119  64.22-1-00   0.109667      0.109667      0.109667          0.168453
```

Note that each item that is from the same group has the same values. I would like to synthesize this dataframe showing only group characteristics, probably even using group as index. It would look like this:

```
     group  groupError level2_error  level3_error      level4_error
64.22-1-00   0.109667      0.109667      0.109667          0.168453
41.20-4-00    4.00153       4.00153       4.00153           9.65689
35.12-3-00    4.81931       4.81931       4.81931        -0.0652749
```

Any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates()`?

Comment: Works perectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle possible input errors (if you aren't 100% that they identical), you can use some form of:

```
df.groupby('group').agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
```

which helps catch outliers too. Otherwise as Paul mentioned, `drop_duplicates()` is perfect.

Edited: Changed `median()` to a function returning the mode, should handle non-numeric data reliably too.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, however it is raising some sort of error: raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate. I will go with the drop_duplicates solution

Comment: For non-numeric data, I think mode() works over median(). But definitely Paul's answer is simpler and works well too :)